# Meaning of "we are of the crowd"

Tags: meaning

In his [poem](https://poetryarchive.org/poem/preston-north-end/), George Szirtes tells a story of a boy attending a football game. When the game is over, "the crowd dissolves, but we are of the crowd, heading into town under sodium street light". What is the meaning of "being of the crowd" in this context?

Comment: It's a fancier way of saying 'but we are part of the crowd', here meaning 'but 'subcrowds' still exist and we're in one'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of [*paradox*](https://web.archive.org/web/20041216011530fw_/http://humanities.byu.edu/rhetoric/Figures/P/paradox.htm).

The crowd in the stadium leaves and dissipates in all directions, including crowds of people heading into town. The writer is swept up in the stream of people going in that direction. While it isn't the crowd in the stadium, there are so many people still surrounding him that he is in a crowd.